# Rotation / Affine matric function using affine matrix in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, affinetransform, rotational-matrices

I can create a plot shown in BLUE which is correct but when I try and rotate it around 90 degrees about point (0,0) the plot in RED is created.  It should just be rotated around 90 degrees about point (0,0).  Anyone know what part of my function / code is causing the problem?

See function along with example code below:

[image: Plot]

```
    %affine matrix rotation about a point rtaffine[theta,rpx,rpy,sigx,sigy,sigz]
%crx cry rpx rpy represent center of rotation
function [rotsig,theta,crpx,crpy,sigx,sigy,sigz] = rtaffine(theta,rpx,rpy,sigx,sigy,sigz) 
    rotsig=[];
    %affinematrix=[];
    siga=[sigx;sigy;sigz];

    r00 = cosd(theta); r01 = -sind(theta); r10 = sind(theta); r11 = cosd(theta);
    affinematrix = [r00, r01, rpx(1,1) - r00*rpx(1,1) - r01*rpy(1,1);...
    r10, r11, rpy(1,1) - r10*rpx(1,1) - r11*rpy(1,1);...
    0, 0, 1];   
    rotsig=affinematrix*siga; %new affine matrix
end


%radial arms
t = linspace(0,2*pi,500);
r=e^0.3063489*t;
x = r.*cos(t);
y = r.*sin(t);
plot(x,y)

hold on

%rotation
theta=90;
z = ones(size(y));
siga=[t;y;z];


rotsig=rtaffine(theta,0,0,siga(1,:),siga(2,:),siga(3,:));

plot(t(1,:),rotsig(1,:),'r-')
```

Comment: I would guess that `siga=[t;y;z];` should be `siga=[x;y;z];`? Also you don't use `rp` anywhere so why include that line? Please comment or provide an explanation to your code btw

Comment: @Dan Just tried changing siga and nothing changed.  I also took out rp was using it for testing just forgot to delete it.

Comment: Also `plot(rotsig(1,:),rotsig(2,:),'r-')` assuming `rotsig` is *2*-by-*n*

Comment: @Dan those two things were the problem thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in `t` and trying to plot against `t` instead of `x` in both cases:

```
siga=[t;y;z];
```

should be

```
siga=[x;y;z];
```

And

```
plot(t(1,:),rotsig(1,:),'r-')
```

should be

```
plot(rotsig(1,:),rotsig(2,:),'r-')
```